# Application_Launching timing

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

What exactly is the timing/thread of the Application_Launching method on WP8? Specifically, in relation to the UI loading/rendering sequence?

I have an app where some global init is being done within Application_Launching. I'm getting a crash report from a method that's called during data binding on the start page's XAML; the crash is consistent with said global init not taking place.

EDIT: I'm calling a native (C++) method which is reading a file into a `malloc`ated memory block in a global variable that's initialized to null. Said variable is dumped as a part of crash reporting; I've got a report where it's null.

Pasting the code would be rather pointless IMHO.

Comment: Can you describe this global init you are doing? Can you please provide some code

Answer (score 1):

When starting the app, the `Launching` event is raised. However, the app can later be put in a dormant state, in a process that is called "tombstoning". When a tombstoned app is resumed, it won't raise the `Launching` event but the `Activated` event instead. It's very likely that you forgot to handle that case.

To test it easily, go in the properties of your Windows Phone project, in the Debug tab, and check the "Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging" option. From there, every time the app is deactivated while the debugger is attached (typically, when pressing the home button on the emulator), the app will be tombstoned, and you can make sure that it resumes properly when switching back to it.

Comment: +1 I agree that probably OP is more likely facing this problem rather than timing. On the other hand - those cases should also be tested and handeled.

Comment: Tombstoning does not erase the global state, last time I've checked. "Global" in this case means - global variables in the native subsystem.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Well it takes only five minutes to test in the emulator anyway

Comment: If this reproduced in the emulator, do you think I'd be asking the question? :) Yes, I've tested reactivation. It does not erase native globals.

Answer (score 0):

I've got another theory. It's not about the library being loaded at the wrong time, it's about the library being **unloaded**. Since almost all of my native functions are static and the state is global, there are no active native objects, and the COM subsystem has a zero ref count on the module. As per COM rules, modules like that are fair game for unloading anytime. On a subsequent native function call, the library is reloaded, but the global state is gone.

From the next version, I'll keep one live native object for the app's lifetime. We'll see if the crash comes back.